# compare with two products in e-commerce website using Laravel framework

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.5

I am developing one e-commerce website using Laravel framework i want to compare two products which is stored in MySQL database, how can i compare pleas help me

Thank in advance.

Comment: Waht properties of products you want to compare? Provide some code

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple thing to do: What usually people compare in products? People like to compare product properties and attributes so simply add two product ID into session and when customer click see compare just display two table and both product properties and attributes and other details on table. I hope it gives you some idea.